# Trouble after moving partition

Tags: grub2, partitioning

After moving the `/` Ubuntu system partition, I'm having trouble on initialization, getting messages:

> can't request region for resource...
>   couldn't get size...".

After some period of time, initialization continues.

I tend to think grub retains information of prior position.
Is that correct?
Anyway, how to solve?

Comment: Merged two partitions?

Comment: Did you backup your data? Resizing partitions is a dangerous thing...

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain _exactly_ what you did. How did you "move" the partition? What exactly do you mean by "move"? What filesystem was on the partition? Where do you see these error messages? What is the _exact_ text of the error messages? The more details you give us, the better your chances of getting a useful answer.

Comment: well did you run `sudo update grub`?

Comment: @terdonMaybe you know, I'm wondering, if resizing or moving partitions changes the UUID?

Comment: @guillermochamorro I don't think so, no. Resizing shouldn't, anyway. Moving, I don't know.

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]!  **:-)** Please [edit] your4 question and provide the exact error information.  *Please help us help you!*  **;-)**